# Silverlight WCF web service hosting on domain.com and www.domain.com

Tags: asp.net, wcf, silverlight, web-services, silverlight-2.0

There's so much stuff on this online but no one seems to be able to answer this... Hopefully someone here will be!

So i have a WCF web service hosted at godaddy.com. Everything works great when i try accessing it using:

http://**www.**domain.com/DataService.svc

problem is when i remove the www i.e.

http://domain.com/DataService.svc

Here's my web.config servicemodel section:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="DataServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="DataServiceBehavior"
      name="DataService">

    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="IDataService"/>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
```

Here's my ServiceReferences.ClientConfig

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IDataService" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
                <security mode="None" />
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://www.domain.ca/DataService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IDataService" contract="Web.IDataService"
            name="BasicHttpBinding_IDataService" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

My service is using a CustomServiceFactory

```
public class CustomServiceHostFactory : ServiceHostFactory
{
    /// <summary>
    /// A custom method to eliminate multiple base addresses from the IIS host creation process
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="serviceType">The service type to be created</param>
    /// <param name="baseAddresses">A list of the base addresses</param>
    /// <returns>A service host</returns>
    protected override ServiceHost CreateServiceHost(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)
    {
        if (baseAddresses.Length > 1)
        {
            ServiceHost customServiceHost =
                new ServiceHost(serviceType, baseAddresses[1]);
            return customServiceHost;
        }

        return new ServiceHost(serviceType, baseAddresses[0]);
    }
}
```

Basically what i would like is my WCF webservice to be reachable whether the user enters domain.com or www.domain.com into his (or her) browser.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

ps. Running IIS 7 with ASP 3.5

Thnaks!
Simon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running across a cross domain issue.  See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189008(VS.95).aspx) for a list of reasons as to why it happens.  As it turns out "www" and no-www are different domains even though they don't seem like it.  You'll need to add a cross domain file.  See [Tim's blog](http://www.google.com/search?q=site:timheuer.com+cross+domain&sourceid=navclient-ff&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1B3GGGL_enUS221US221) for good info

Comment: It's weird bc i had a clientaccesspolicy.xml but its only when i added the crossdomain.xml thats it finally worked. Could it be due to godaddy? Well at least its working now. Thanks!

Comment: Interesting.  It's actually easy to muck up cross domain files.  Maybe this tool will help: http://www.franksworld.com/Utilities/CrossDomainPolicyChecker/Default.aspx  gl!